Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core vulnerability issue - fix
what is the latest version of "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core" in the series of 6 like Version="6. * . *" In nuget gallery it is not available any thing later than v2.2.0
But when I use     net6.0 it internally refer Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.dll version (6.0.3024.21619) and sonatype scan stage in build pipeline complains about vulnerability/risk CVE-2024-35264 associated with it and build fails. How to overcome it?

Just like what you can see here, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core packages has been deprecated. Since Kestrel is included by default in asp.net core, you might need to install the latest .net 6 runtime to fix the vulnerability. Could you pls run dotnet --info on your machine and see whether the .net runtime is 6.0.32?
